# event expected not to raise is raising

Tags: asp.net, unit-testing, events, event-handling, nunit

I have an **event** and a **raising method** as below :

```
public class Events {

    public event EventHandler<CustomEventArgs> Succeed;

    public virtual void OnSucceed(object sender, params object[] data)
    {
        CustomEventArgs args = new CustomEventArgs(data);

        EventHandler<CustomEventArgs> _succeed = Succeed;

        if (_succeed != null)
        {
            _succeed(sender, args);
        }

    }}
```

I have created a **unit test** for the **OnSucceed** method (using [FluentAssertions](http://fluentassertions.codeplex.com/) ):

```
    [Test]
    public void SucceedShouldNotBeRaisedTest()
    {
        Events events = new Events();

        events.MonitorEvents();

        events.OnSucceed(this,"somedata");

        events.ShouldNotRaise("Succeed");
    }
```

as there is no subscriber to the event then I expect it not to raise Succeed event

but the test fails as Succeed event **is raised** . what's wrong with this ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `events.MonitorEvents();`, *FluentAssertions* automatically subscribe to the public events to detect when an event has been raised.

Your test is failing because your condition will always evaluate to `true`: `if (_succeed != null)`. When testing, the event will always be different from `null`

Now I would like to recommend you to following approach proposed by Jon Skeet:

```
public event EventHandler<CustomEventArgs> Succeed = delegate { } ;
```

With the above event declaration, your event will never be `null` (an event cannot be assigned from outside of its class)

Note: You *can assign the **delegate behind the event to null inside its class*** like this:

```
this.Succeed = null;
```

The above statement is **assigning the delegate behind the event to null, not the event itself**. Usually you won't need to do something like this, but in case you do, you would have to re-initialize the event like this:

```
this.Succeed = null;
this.Succeed = delegate { };
```

If you follow these suggestions, your event will never be null and you won't need to call the `if(this.MyEvent != null)` condition in order to raise your events anymore. (Note that this condition was totally technical and it's not related to the domain itself.)

Now that you have removed that *technical condition* you can **actually focus in the domain rules** to decide when to raise the event.

The last step would be to remove: `if (_succeed != null)` and add a condition indicating if the event should or should not be raised based on your current domain

```
if(shouldRaiseEvent)
{
    EventHandler<CustomEventArgs> _succeed = Succeed;

    _succeed(...);
}
```

For your tests, you just need to configure your Subject Under Test with the required conditions in order to raise or not raise your events.

Full sample:

```
public class Events {

public event EventHandler<CustomEventArgs> Succeed = delegate { };

public virtual void OnSucceed(object sender, params object[] data)
{
    if (/*[optional] here your domain condition that will indicate if the event should be raised*/)
    {
        // this is a best practice to deal with multi-threading situations
        var _succeed = this.Succeed;
        var args = new CustomEventArgs(data);

        _succeed(sender, args);
    }

}
}
```

Comment: thank you sir , then which assigning null statement is preferred ? I feel better with the first one actually ( event = delegate {} )